# select() function for annotations from annotation db is not working

Tags: r, select, dplyr, annotations

I am trying to annotate gene symbols with Entrez gene IDs from org.Hs.eg.db.
I did it before using:

```
select(org.Hs.eg.db, keys=mykeys, columns=c("SYMBOL", "ENTREZID"), keytype="SYMBOL")
```

mykeys is a vector of gene symbols.
It worked before, but not i am getting:

```
`error in usemethod( depth ) no applicable method for 'select_'applied to an object of class "c('OrgDb', 'AnnotationDb', 'envRefClass', '.environment', 'refClass', 'environment', 'refObject', 'AssayData')`"
```

Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I solved it myself:

`AnnotationDbi::select(org.Hs.eg.db, keys=mykeys, columns=c("SYMBOL", "ENTREZID"), keytype="SYMBOL")`